# How can I use an existing opened window in my test?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm using robot framework and I need to run a test where it should work on a manually opened window.

Using  `Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}` opens a new browser window.

I want to use the browser window that is already opened. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Selenium cannot interact with a manually opened browser.

The seleniumhq issue that addresses this (and which was closed as "not feasible") is here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help. 
Another question please, I want to read a div which will contain something like this: "Verification Code: 12345"
I need to get this 12345 and store it in a variable. How can I do that?